# create a for loop with increments, but other variables stay the same

Tags: r

hey guys i would like to increase variable pi1 from -1 to 0 by 0.0001 steps under the condition that all the other variables stay the same..
how can I do that?

this is what I've tried so far

```
for(i in seq(from=-1, to=0, by=0.001)){
set.seed(1234)

n <- 2000
b0 <- 0
pi1 <- 0
b1 <- 0
b2 <- -1/1000
b3 <- 1/5

z <- runif(n,0,25)
ov <- rnorm(n,0,1)

d <- -1/2 + pi1[i] * z + 1/2 * ov + rnorm(n,0,1) > 0
y <- b0 + b1 * d + b2 * z + b3 * ov + rnorm(n,0,1/10)
```

any suggestions what could by the issue?

Best Freddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, I'm missing something but can't you assign the value of the loop variable `i` to `pi1`?

```r
for(i in seq(from=-1, to=0, by=0.001)){
  set.seed(1234)
  print(i)
  
  n <- 2000
  b0 <- 0
  pi1 <- i
  b1 <- 0
  b2 <- -1/1000
  b3 <- 1/5
  
  z <- runif(n,0,25)
  ov <- rnorm(n,0,1)
  
  d <- -1/2 + pi1 * z + 1/2 * ov + rnorm(n,0,1) > 0
  y <- b0 + b1 * d + b2 * z + b3 * ov + rnorm(n,0,1/10)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need `for` loop. You can use `outer` like below

```
set.seed(1234)

n <- 2000
b0 <- 0
pi1 <- 0
b1 <- 0
b2 <- -1 / 1000
b3 <- 1 / 5

z <- runif(n, 0, 25)
ov <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)

pi1 <- seq(-1, 0, by = 1e-3)
# we can use `outer`
d <- -1 / 2 + t(outer(pi1, z)) + 1 / 2 * ov + rnorm(n, 0, 1) > 0
y <- b0 + b1 * d + b2 * z + b3 * ov + rnorm(n, 0, 1 / 10)
```